# Format hash value to hex-string when using generics for different sha2-hash methods

Tags: string, generics, rust, formatting, sha2

I'm currently working with the 'sha2' library.
One of the functions in my project is supposed to calculate the hash of a file using
different methods (Sha224, Sha256, Sha384, Sha512).
All of the hash methods use the trait `sha2::Digest` and
all return a `GenericArray<u8, Self::OutputSize>`.
However, since a generic type is used, i get following error message:

```
cannot add `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize` to `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize`
```

with this code:

```
use sha2::{Digest, Sha224, Sha256, Sha384, Sha512};
use std::error::Error;
use std::{env, fs, io, process};

//...

impl AutoSha {

//...

    fn calc_hash<T: Digest + io::Write>(&self, file_path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut hasher = T::new();
        let mut file = fs::File::open(file_path)?;

        io::copy(&mut file, &mut hasher)?;
        let hash = hasher.finalize();

        Ok(format!("{:x}", hash)) // This results in the error message
    }
}

//Call example:
let auto_sha: AutoSha = AutoSha::new();
let hash = auto_sha.calc_hash::<Sha256>("path/to/file".to_string());
```

Using, for example, `Sha256::new()` instead of `T::new()` works fine.
I have tried to set both 'OutputSizeUser' and 'OutputSize' as trait bounds but was unable
to find what namespace they are located in.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/crypto-common/0.1.3/crypto_common/trait.OutputSizeUser.html#associatedtype.OutputSize) it is supposedly part of 'crypto_common' which should be included in the project as it is a dependency of 'sha2', but i was not able to include it.
Additionally, i do not know whether that would solve my issue either.

**How can i format the return value of 'hasher.finalize()' to a hexadecimal string?**

### Full error log

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize` to `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize`
   --> src/main.rs:80:28
    |
80  |         Ok(format!("{:x}", hash))
    |                            ^^^^ no implementation for `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize + <T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize`
    |
    = help: the trait `Add` is not implemented for `<T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LowerHex` for `GenericArray<u8, <T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize>`
note: required by a bound in `ArgumentV1::<'a>::new_lower_hex`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::__export::format_args` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
73  |     fn calc_hash<T: Digest + io::Write>(&self, file_path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> where <T as OutputSizeUser>::OutputSize: Add {
    |                                                                                                     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `hash-cmp` due to previous error
```

I have tried to use the recommended solution with `std::ops::Add` but did not manage to get it to work either.

### Useful links

- [sha2 Documentation](https://docs.rs/sha2/latest/sha2/)
- [Full source code (Github)](https://github.com/B1TC0R3/hash-cmp/blob/main/src/main.rs)

Comment: Please add the full error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting/reading for a while i found following solution:

```rust
fn calc_hash<T: Digest + io::Write>(&self, file_path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut hasher = T::new();
    let mut file = fs::File::open(file_path)?;

    io::copy(&mut file, &mut hasher)?;
    let hash = hasher.finalize();

    let mut hash_string = "".to_string();
    for byte in hash.iter() {
        hash_string = format!("{}{:02x}", hash_string, byte);
    }
    Ok(hash_string)
}
```

I'm basically just iterating over each byte of the `GenericArray` and then concat it with the end result.